# Nagios - Custom Variables in Log File

Tags: logging, nagios

Is it possible to add a custom variable in nagios.log?

I have some objects with customs variables (i.e: _ClientName) and I want it to show in nagios.log when it fails or gives some error, along with the others variables that are already logged.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, it is not possible to customise the format of the nagios.log output without modifying the Nagios code itself.

You may be able to write an NEB plugin that customises logs, by catching the NEB_CALLBACK_LOGDATA callback and modifying the log content, but this would be pretty advanced wizardry.